# How to deploy a Qt application from one Ubuntu to another

Tags: qt, ubuntu, deployment

I built a Qt 5.15.1 application on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and I am trying to run it on a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, before sending it to a colleague.

I have:

- created plugins and platforms subdirs in the application directory, with the Qt libraries and plugins copied in
- set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the libraries, and the app loads (ldd reports all libraries are loaded).

But I get an error:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I change the plugin with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland-egl`, I get the same message except stating
that `wayland-egl` can't be loaded.

All the libraries and plugins were copied from the 18.04.5 machine where the app was built
and runs.

Presumably, something is missing on the 22.04.3 system that is required to load the plugin,
but the error message isn't enlightening.

I viewed the plugin `libqxcb.so` in *GHex* (binary editor) to look for  any libraries it loaded, and copied them into a file. I checked them against the libraries on 22.04.3, and 27 were already in `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu`, 4 were Qt libraries, which I copied into `...linux-gnu` from 18.04.5, and I also copied the missing `libxcb-xinerama.so.0` from 18.04.5:

```
- libQt5XcbQpa.so.5        <== Qt
- libfontconfig.so.1       -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libfreetype.so.6         -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libz.so.1                -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libQt5Gui.so.5           <== Qt
- libQt5DBus.so.5          <== Qt
- libQt5Core.so.5          <== Qt
- libGL.so.1               -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libpthread.so.0          -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libX11-xcb.so.1          -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-icccm.so.4        -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-image.so.0        -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-shm.so.0          -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-keysyms.so.1      -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-randr.so.0        -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-render-util.so.0  -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-render.so.0       -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-shape.so.0        -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-sync.so.1         -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-xfixes.so.0       -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb-xinerama.so.0     <== missing !!!
- libxcb-xkb.so.1          -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxcb.so.1              -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libXext.so.6             -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libX11.so.6              -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxkbcommon-x11.so.0    -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libxkbcommon.so.0        -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libdl.so.2               -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libstdc++.so.6           -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libm.so.6                -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libgcc_s.so.1            -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
- libc.so.6                -- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
...
```

However, my app is still giving me the same error message. What is going on? And how do I debug it?

Update: I ran ldd directly on `libqxcb.so` and all libraries are resolved. It is beginning to look like a bug in 5.15 / 18.04 `libqxcb` such that it fails on later versions of Ubuntu, not a link error.

Comment: Copying libraries is not the way how it should go on Linux. Better way is to create deb package and specify all the dependendenies and resolve them through package manager.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but that is not the question I asked. BTW I started there with linuxdeployqt (https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt). It failed saying "ERROR: ldd outputline ... version 'Qt_5.15' not found" for binary. Yet running ldd on my binary resolved all libraries, and my pathname is Qt/5.15.1, not Qt_5.15, so going that route meant I had to debug why linuxdeployqt had hallucinated that name.